# Spry Tabbed Panels Some Tabs work, some don't

Tags: tabs, nested, spry, tabbed

I'm currently working with Spry Tabbed Panels in a Site. I've nested a set of panels inside of another set of panels. My problem is that 2 out of 4 tabs in the first panel don't work. And two out of four tabs in the nested set of panels don't work.

Here is a link to the site for an example:
http://emilymagnuson.com/trustbank/index.html

Comment: Also to be more specific,

Comment: These Tabs Work: Mine, Business, Accounts and Goals                     These Tabs Don't Work: Commerce, About Us, Funds, About Us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure looks broken. You need to fix that if you want spry to work properly. For example on line 336 of the source code there is an extra `</div>` closing tag. I would review your code and make sure that all your HTML elements are placed properly.

Comment: Okay, I went through the code and line 62 was marked as invalid, and I have no idea why. I remember putting it there. And it has a purpose and it has a closing tag, so I'm confused why it's marked that way. do you have any idea?

Comment: There was a lot of error. You had a form tag that wasn't closed and many of your panels were not placed where they needed to be in order to work properly. Here is a working example of what you are trying to accomplish: [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tlaverdure/PKUPr/embedded/result/). You can copy and paste the code. Please mark this answer as the correct one if it answers the question.

Comment: Thank you so much! An extra div tag was the culprit. But I will still go through the code and look for that Form end tag.

Comment: I think that form tag is closed.