# Is there an easy way to find broken HTML code in Dreamweaver?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Is there an easy way to find broken HTML code in Dreamweaver?

I've got an issue and I keep loosing count. Is there a Dreamweaver trick to this?

Comment: Do you have a specific problem? Post your code.

Comment: I suggest reading some basic html tutorials. A little will go a long way.

Comment: +1 to negate the downvote, the question is relevant. A piece of advice, whenever I start a new element, I always add the closing tags before I put anything inside it, also code indenting and good formatting helps A LOT.

Comment: Thanks Dominic! I'm a beginner. And I'm learning to go back through the code after dreamweaver writes a lot of it, just to make it easier to spot things.

Comment: @Mick Jones Here is my specific issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484226/spry-tabbed-pannels-some-tabs-work-some-dont/14484352#14484352

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try turning on 'Highlight Invalid Code' and 'Syntax Error Alerts In Info Bar' both about halfway down the toolbar on the left adjacent to the coding/design window.

Highlight Invalid Code will show all unclosed HTML tags in yellow and Syntax Error Alerts will notify you that there is a problem with your scripts, although it will not tell you exactly where.

EDIT: Syntax Error Alerts does give a small indication of where the problem is by showing which line has a problem BUT it often just shows that there is a problem with the last line of the script usually due to the fact that a function hasn't been closed properly somewhere further up.

Comment: @c.k. sorry I'm totally unfamiliar with PHP. I think you'll need an IDE targetted at PHP like PHPStorm. See more options at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116292/what-is-the-best-ide-for-php or Google 'PHP IDE'. (IDE stands for integrated development environment. A PHP IDE should have all relevant tools and features needed to develop with PHP.)